# why it says that my var is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't understand why this doesn't work: it should take the text of ("#name") and write in another html page that I open on click on the button, but when I open the other page it says that the "username" is undefined, how can I pass the value of that?

```
username = [];

$("#main_page").ready(function() {
  $("#name").focus();   

  $("#name").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      console.log("ok");
      $('#login').click();
    }
  });

  $("#login").click(function() {
    username[0] = $("#name").val();
    console.log(username);
    window.location.replace("chat");
  });
});

$("#chat").ready(function(){
  console.log(username[0] + " recived");
  $("#username_title").append(username[0]);
});
```

Is it wrong to use `$('#chat').ready`? Because it runs the code filled in it in the main_page too.

In the two file html i gave an id to the body for use .ready, but I think it's wrong

Comment: This is not how JS code works. It only operates on a single page (the currently loaded one) so therefore you cannot send variables in memory as you're attempting to do. Instead you'd need to pass the value in the querystring, or save them in localStorage or a cookie, and then retrieve them once the next page has loaded.

Comment: And use var, let or const to declare variables

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh...ok(you sad me)

Comment: @baao i didn't use it because i red somewhere that I must do in this way for a global var

Comment: Maybe, you should take a look at [HTML5 Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put "username" in a cookie, and get "username" from the cookie in the next page "chat". You also could use localStorage or sessionStorage instead of cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about page load and page unload

the scope of a variable is just inside these events means that no jq js or any web code(client side) will work before or after that

Means you cant write a code and expect it to work even after page reload its a whole new start then **although you can pass the username as a querystring and fetch it after page is reloaded**